# Does a person affected by the power of the Time Stone remember what happened before their time was manipulated?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

At the end of the film Avengers: Infinity War, we see Thanos use the all of the infinity stones, including the stone of time. My question is does the stone of time erase the characters' memories?
 It seems like it does, because Time Stone affects the whole person.

Comment: Hello! I believe Vision is an android and not a creature, which has lead to some confusion about your question! It would help greatly if you could edit your title and Q by correcting the terminology.

Comment: @DarthLocke Like that?

Comment: @DarthLocke I cite Vision just as an example.

Comment: @DarthLocke 
But I only have one line left "Does Time Stone affect on person's memory or not?".  It will be really misunderstandable question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85935/discussion-between-darth-locke-and-ver-nick).

Comment: The Time Stone was also used on __Dormammu__, does he count as a person though?

Comment: @Oliver_C Sorry, I haven't watched Dr. Strange yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Does Time Stone affect on person's memory or not?"

It's likely that the entity **directly** affected (such as the Vision) would have no memory of **highly localised** time reversal affecting them. Recall that in *Infinity War*, the reversal is limited to **just** the Vision.

However, there are indications that certain individuals *can* remember what has happened to them but these tend to be magic related individuals.

In *Doctor Strange* during the battle in Hong Kong we see Strange reverse time and Wong is found impaled on a pipe.

As time is reversed he is lifted off the pipe (a reversal of being thrown on to it) and talks to Strange. Strange then magically allows him to move forward in time with him and Mordo while elsewhere time still runs backwards.

As Wong does so he looks back at the pipe as though he realises what has happened to him.

[image]